# Extend Rails app with standard content pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I developed an App with Rails 3.2

We realized that we may end up having many 'standard' content pages, mainly text documenting the application itself. Nothing the application users will be playing with.

Is there an extension (plugin, gem) I could use to add page to my app like we would normally do on a standard CMS?

I want to be able to delegate the addition/nodfication of content to the admin rather than coding it in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem with our knowledge base, and chose to use [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/) for it.

This gives us something similar to [developer.github.com](http://developer.github.com/) in term of end-user. And the code is written in markdown (developer.github.com is [open source](https://github.com/github/developer.github.com)).

This way, all our documentation is written in markdown in static files.
Support people can write them without having to know about programming. With the GitHub Mac App, they can very easily push and pull from a repository.